# How to show blank record in sql if duplicate rows exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL Query Results,

```
EmployeeID    EmployeeName    Department
1             John            Sales
2             Robert          Sales
3             Sudhir          Sales
4             Roj             Development
```

Output Should be

```
EmployeeID    EmployeeName    Department
1             John            Sales
2             Robert          
3             Sudhir          
4             Roj             Development
```

Comment: I suggest you to let sql-server to extract data, and to let the client/business/report layer to render them in the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
( 
   SELECT EmployeeID, EmployeeName, Department,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) rownum
  FROM table1
)
SELECT
  EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  CASE rownum
    WHEN 1 THEN Department
    ELSE ''
  END AS Department
FROM CTE
ORDER BY EmployeeID;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4da97/4)

**Note that:** Try not to do these sort of formatting stuff in SQL. SQL *is not* about formatting.

Comment: Yes, It helped. I used two columns: DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT Department)) AS 'A',
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Department ORDER BY Department) AS 'B'
And Then used following in select statement:
case when convert(varchar(5),[B])='1' then convert(varchar(5),[A]) else '' end 'NO.'

Comment: @Mahmoud Gamal, Does this command run on MYSQL? I tried to run it but it has errors.

Comment: @kiLLua - No it won't run. Mysql doesn't have row number function like SQL Server, but there are other workaround to achieve the same. But, for this issue, I don't recommend do any formatting for the data in the sql side, formatting should be done in the front end not in SQL. So, if you are trying to do the same, do it in the front end not in sql. Just select your data normally and then in the front end side it will be very easy to format it the way you want. I hope this helps.