# SQL Replace duplicate entries with blanks

Tags: sql, sybase, sqlanywhere, sybase-asa

I have a SQL Table like this one:

[image: SQl table]

and I want the output to be like this:

[image: Output]

Basically:

- replace duplicates with blanks but

  - if **col6** value is different from the previous row for the same
    **col1**
    value, all the data fields should be included.
- col10 values are blank.
- col12 is removed.

I am struggling to create a query. 
I found this: [CTE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13742572/how-to-show-blank-record-in-sql-if-duplicate-rows-exists)

and tried to run the following:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
( 
   SELECT DBA.s12.*,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DBA.s12.col6 ORDER BY(SELECT 1)) rownum
  FROM DBA.s12
)
SELECT
   DBA.s12.col1,
   DBA.s12.col2,
   DBA.s12.col3,
   DBA.s12.col4,
   DBA.s12.col5,
   DBA.s12.col7, 
   DBA.s12.col8,
   DBA.s12.col9,
   DBA.s12.col10,
   DBA.s12.col11,
   DBA.s12.col12,
  CASE rownum
    WHEN 1 THEN DBA.s12.col6
    ELSE ''
  END AS col6
FROM CTE
ORDER BY DBA.s12.col1;
```

but I get an error `"Could not execute statement. Syntax error or access violation"`

Can anyone shed some light on where my query has a syntax error/access violation or have a better method to extract the data?

Comment: Which Sybase product are you using? ASE, ASA?

Comment: @MichaelGardner Sybase Central 16.0.0.1324

Comment: @MichaelGardner can you tell me the tool which I would require to do this? I can google/read documentation for it.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: @Mohsen I don't remember if I found a solution to this. I haven't worked on this in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if this will work, but maybe try to replace

```
END AS col6
```

with

```
END AS DBA.s12.col6
```